# Calculate days in between given start date and end date in php

Tags: php

I have $start_date & $end_date.

I need to find out number of days with name's of days.

I tried following code snipet :

```
$start_date = '20-07-2012';
$end_date = '22-07-2012';
$start = strtotime($start_date);
$end = strtotime($end_date);
$interval = 2;
$out='';
$int = 24*60*60*$interval;
for($i= $start;$i<= $end; $i += $int ){

    echo date('d-m-Y',$i).'<br />';
}
```

output :

```
28-11-2014
30-11-2014
```

But my expected out is like :

```
28-11-2014 => friday
30-11-2014 => saturday
```

let me know what should be php code to yeild the expected output.

Comment: Please check http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   // $array[desc:day count starting w 1][desc: 'date' or 'day'];
   // $array[2]['day'];
<?php
$start = '27-11-2014';
$end = '1-12-2014';
    function date_difference($start, $end)
    {
        $first_date = strtotime($start);
        $second_date = strtotime($end);
        $offset = $second_date-$first_date; 
        $result = array();
        for($i = 0; $i <= floor($offset/24/60/60); $i++) {
            $result[1+$i]['date'] = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($start. ' + '.$i.'  days'));
            $result[1+$i]['day'] = date('l', strtotime($start. ' + '.$i.' days'));
        }
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($result);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    date_difference($start, $end);
?>
```

result

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 27-11-2014
            [day] => Thursday
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 28-11-2014
            [day] => Friday
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 29-11-2014
            [day] => Saturday
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 30-11-2014
            [day] => Sunday
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [date] => 01-12-2014
            [day] => Monday
        )

)
```

Comment: @pihu quickly before bed tell me what else you want this function to do or return?

Answer (score 1):

Day name is in `'l'` (lowercase L).

If you need just string, use:

```
echo date('d-m-Y => l', $i) . '<br />';
```

If you want an array, use:

```
$days = array();

for ($i = $start;$i <= $end; $i += $int) {
    $days[] = array(
        'date' => date('d-m-Y', $i),
        'day'  => date('l', $i)
    );
}

print_r($days);
```

More info about `date` in the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: @pihu: if you have more dates, just change interval to one day instead of current two days, the rest stay the same. In `date` function you can you whatever from the Manual page, or text, so you can make the output as you need.

Comment: Also if possible let me know with son=me modifications in above codes how can i get the output as days name and date for all days from start date to end date that is if start date is 28-11-2014 and end date is 04-12-2014 then output should be like :                 {
 {
   date: 28-11-2014
   day : friday
 }
 {
   date: 29-11-2014
   day : saturday
 }
 {
   date: 30-11-2014
   day : sunday
 }
 {
   date: 01-12-2014
   day : monday
 }
 {
   date: 02-12-2014
   day : tuesday
 }
 {
   date: 03-12-2014
   day : wednesday
 }
 {
   date: 04-12-2014
   day : thursday
 }
 
}

Comment: @pihu: I've updated my answer, see the `$days` array.

Comment: @pihu with my answer below you can just pass the dates the function will give you an array like `$day[1]['day'] or $day[1]['date']`

Answer (score 0):

try this modified code

```
    <?php

    $start_date = '20-07-2012';
    $end_date = '22-07-2012';
    $start = strtotime($start_date);
    $end = strtotime($end_date);
    $interval = 2;
    $out='';
    $int = 24*60*60*$interval;
    for($i= $start;$i<= $end; $i += $int ){

        echo date('d-m-Y => l',$i).'<br />';
    }
?>
```

output :

```
20-07-2012 => Friday
22-07-2012 => Sunday
```